# API Fetch update only one data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

How can I update only one data through API? I want to change from `status: 4` to `status: 5`

Here's my code

```
export const cancelRequest = async id => {
 const response = await fetch(`API_URL/link/link/${id}`, {
  method: 'put',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${Auth.getToken()}`,
   },
  });
  return getData(response);
};
```

Calling it through another file

```
const onCancelRequest = async id => {
  let cancelItem = dataAll.filter(item => item.id == id);

  await TriggerRequestAPI.cancelRequest(id)
    .then(data => {
      data.json();
      cancelItem[0].status = 5;
      setIsAll(cancelItem);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your item first then call the API:

```
const onCancelRequest = async id => {
  const cancelItems = dataAll.filter(item => item.id == id);

  if(cancelItems.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  // Update the item
  cancelItems[0].status = 5;

  // Then call the API
  await TriggerRequestAPI.cancelRequest(id, cancelItems[0])
    .then(data => {
      return data.json();
    })
    .then(item => {
      setIsAll(cancelItems);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

**API**:

```
export const cancelRequest = async(id, item) => {
 const response = await fetch(`API_URL/link/link/${id}`, {
  method: 'put',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${Auth.getToken()}`,
   },
  body: JSON.stringify(item) // item to update
  });
  return getData(response);
};
```

Comment: Hello @Fraction I'm having this on my console  data.json is not a function maybe because I have two .then?

Comment: What's the output of  `console.log(data)` ?